# When Adding Google Ads Getting Error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, ads, google-ads-data-hub

- I added google Ads in my project and
  I am getting the error that is given below in the image.
  I got code from Github
  I just wanted to show ads but didn't.
  I upgrade my flutter SDK and do everything in [image: This is the Console Error]my possession. Looking for Help.

[image: This is the Ad Helper Class]

Comment: Update you gradle version, the error states that.

Comment: not happening anything